# Rails install fails - cause by Nokogiri gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, nokogiri

I am trying to setup a ruby on rails environment on my mac in order to start using the RubyMine IDE. 
I have used homebrew, rbenv and all other required libraries in order to install ruby/rails - however when I `sudo gem install rails` the install fails due to :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161110-767-xwnfls.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I have tried to install Nokogiri on it's own and I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/.autotest
```

I really hope somebody can help me as I am quite a noob to RonR and I feel like things have gotten messy directory/permission wise,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a quick look at a small part of the error that you have provided us.

```
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
```

It's trying to tell you that you do not have `zlib`, so let's get it. Since you said you're using a Mac, I would install a package manager like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Try doing `brew install zlib` to install this package.

Additionally, if you're starting out learning Ruby, regardless of what platform you are using, it might be helpful to use something like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to manage different versions of Ruby and the gems that go along with those versions. You will run into less permissions issues (e.g. having to run `gem install` as a privileged user), some of which may be easy to solve, but some of which may send you down a rabbit hole for a few hours.

Comment: Hey, 
I'm not that much of a noob in the sense that I've installed homebrew, rbev and rvm as stated in the question context. 
Secondly, zlib is not a package available on homebrew. There is only a lzlib which I already have installed.
Thanks

Comment: Do `brew search zlib`. I'm on OS X 10.10 and have the package. It may not be in the main repository yet. Sorry, I misread initially that you already have everything set up with `rbenv`. If that is the case, you should not be using `sudo` to run `gem install`. See if you can find `zlib` by searching for it, I do remember setting it up on 10.11 from Caskroom or some other prefix.

Comment: I've tried searching for it with no luck :( im on 10.12 by the way and I can't seem to figure out how using Caskroom will help me install it ? 
Thanks again

Comment: @AcidMicrowave: I managed to find [this potential solution](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/234#issuecomment-140415906) for you on GitHub. Let me know if it works.